# Units of a number and if over by 1 it counts as two?

Tags: units-of-measurement

I am new to programming using Java and I can't use anything fancy to solve this. I assume it is some simple math but I can't seem to figure it out.

I need to determine how many units of 25 (in miles) the package is being shipped (remember that parts of 25 count as a full 25, so 75 is 3 units of 25 while 76 is 4 units of 25).

So how do I do that math to find out how many units the number the user enters will be. This is by 25.

I tried division but it wont give me two units if I do    miles / 25.

Please help!

### Edit

I have found online someone using (miles + 24) / 25;

But I do not understand that...

Answer (score 0):

You could round it. Most computer languages have some means of rounding integers.

Many languages today also have a mod operator (often the % sign) which returns the remainder after division.

So, you can use something like

```
(1)    int wholeUnits = miles / 25;

(2)     remainder = miles % 25;

(3)   if (remainder != 0)  wholeUnits = wholeUnits +1;
```

So, (1) determines the number of whole units -- 75 would return 3, 74 would return 2, and 76 would return 3.

(2) would give you the remainder when dividing by 25.  So, 75 % 25 = 0.  76 % 25 = 1.  And 74 % 25 = 24.

(3) if the remainder is other than zero, you need to add one to the wholeUnits.  So, 75 would have a zero remainder so it would just be 3.  74 would return 24, and thus you'd add 1 to the 2 you already have, getting 3 whole units.  And 76 would return (3+1) = 4.

So, there are different ways of doing it, depending on the language you're using.  The easiest thing is to figure out what the round function is and use it.  But you can do it the long way with these three steps if you prefer.